# How can use IF & MAX together?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, max

How do I perform the following function in Excel?
Currently Column C display the MAX value of D4:F4.
However I need it to display an alternate value.

For instance if MAX Value is from column D, it'll display "TRAN", or if MAX value value comes from column E, It'll display "VERT" and lastly if it comes from column F, it'll display "LONG"

[image: VM]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ties for max? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean if column D,E, F if any two columns contain the same value and that value is the Max, what is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values cannot tie (i.e. the max value can only occur once in the range you can use the following formula in `C4` for example:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(MAX(D4:F4),D4:F4,0),"TRAN","VERT","LONG")
```

You would then drag that formula down as many rows as is required.

If there can be repeated Max values e.g. D4 and E4 were both to contain 1.439, you would need a specify how to handle this and an adapted/different formula would be required.

Example of checking for this and handling:

```
 =IF(COUNTIF(D4:F4,MAX(D4:F4))>1,"MyChosenResponse",CHOOSE(MATCH(MAX(D4:F4),D4:F4,0),"TRAN","VERT","LONG"))
```

Comment: Thanks. My value will never have a but thanks for the answer for handling similar values too though.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using index-match or vlookup to make a neat formula, avoiding many if statement. Put "TRAN", "VERT", "LONG" above the cooresponding column and use formula below:

```
=INDEX($D$1:$F$1, MATCH(C4,D4:F4,0))
```

[image]

The result would be 
[image]